# Function "pwr()" is not working properly

Tags: c

I'm new to C and was just making a function "pwr()" to raise a number to the power which are both specified in the program within the parenthesis. A blank screen appears or it just gives a value of 0 and 1 to "First Number" and "Second Number:" respectively.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int pwr( int, int);

int main(){
int num, numn;
num == pwr(5,2);
numn == pwr(2,5);
printf("First Number:%d\n",num);
printf("Second Number:%d\n", numn);
return 0;
}

int pwr(int c,int pr)
{
int res = 1;
int i=0;

if(pr<0){
    printf("Imaginary\n");
    return 0;

}
for(i=0;i=pr;i++){
    res = res*c;
}
return res;
}
```

Can someone tell me my mistake.

Comment: you know you can use `pow` function that already exists in `math.h` right?

Comment: What do you think == does?

Comment: You might like to read up what `for(;;)` expects.

Comment: `num  == pwr()` should be `num = pwr()`, and beyond that, you should learn to use a debugger. It's an indispensable skill for a programmer. Would have shown you that mixed up your operators very fast.

Comment: Also you might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Raising a number to a negative power doesn't give an "imaginary" result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
num == pwr(5,2);
numn == pwr(2,5);
```

To :

```
num = pwr(5,2);
numn = pwr(2,5);
```

And :

```
for(i=0;i=pr;i++){
    res = res*c;
  }
```

To :

```
for(i=0;i<pr;i++){
        res = res*c;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept my answer by upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines

```
num == pwr(5,2);
numn == pwr(2,5);
```

To

```
num = pwr(5,2);
numn = pwr(2,5);
```

Because **==** is an equal to operator and **=** is an assingment operator.
Here assigning the return value of the function to a variable.

And change these lines

```
 for(i=0;i=pr;i++){
   res = res*c;
 }
```

To

```
for(i=0;i<pr;i++){
  res = res*c;
}
```

Because powering up the first value(c) to second value(pr) 
Note:so multipliying c -> pr times